# How to compute buffers for certain features?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I used the following snippet of codes for finding buffer.

```
def buffer(self):
    layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
    distance = float( self.dlg.DistancelineEdit.text() )
    city = self.dlg.Citycombo.currentText()
    expr = QgsExpression('"name_1" = \'' + city + '\'' )
    it = layer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( expr ) )
    feature = it.next()

    # Perform a buffer on the feature geometry
    myBufferPolygon = feature.geometry().buffer(dist, 50)
```

It is raising two errors

```
feature = it.next()
    StopIteration.
```

2.distance = float( self.dlg.DistancelineEdit.text() )
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your feature request does not return any matching features. That's why the resulting iterator is empty.

For numerical value input use a spinbox instead of a text field.

Comment: Could u say me how to stop the iterator error please?

Comment: You have to figure out why the feature request returns no result